# What folder should the ".android" junction point to?

Tags: android, android-studio, junction

I installed the Android Studio.  First it gave me an error installing the built-tools-21.1.1, but the android 21.1.2 folder was already in there.  I downloaded 21.1.1, which had a folder named android-5.0.  I put it alongside the "21.1.2" folder, clicked retry on the error message, and the installation succeeded.  However, there was an error that it couldn't create an AVD.

After launching the AVD Manager, I set up a new AVD, but when I clicked finished, nothing happened.  It basically failed silently.

I launched the SDK Manager as an administrator, and got a couple errors regarding a failure to download a file.

Instead of using the AVD Manager in Android Studio, I launched the one in `%USERPROFILE%\Local\Android\sdk` folder.  When I tried to create the AVD from there, I finally got a useful error message.  It couldn't find the file `%USERPROFILE%\.android\avd\` (the system cannot find the path specified).

As it turns out, the .android junction refers to a location that does not exist.  I now realize I had an older Android SDK installed years ago, and at that time the junction refered to a folder a `D:\.android`.  I think I was using a separate drive root as my user profile folder.

Should `%USERPROFILE%\.android` even be a junction?  Or should it just be a normal folder?
If it is supposed to be a junction, where should it point?

Comment: It's a directory, not a symbolic link.

Comment: I deleted the old junction, then recreated it to point to AppData\Local\Android.  That directory now contains the "sdk" and the "avd" directories, and the AVD was successfully created.  It still won't run, but I'm going to try reinstalling Android Studio, now that the .android junction no longer points to a non-existent target.

Comment: After reinstalling Android Studio with the junction fixed, everything went flawlessly.  The SDK Manager was able to successfully download its lists without errors, and now all the android system images I was missing have shown up.  I'm installing them now.  Can't believe something left over from an old installation screwed things up that bad.  Android Studio's installer should really check to ensure that the ".android" folder is set up right (either as a folder or as a junction with a valid target) if it's going to rely on it.